# AndroidManifest.xml validation errors and app not recognizing uses:permission's

Tags: android, xml, validation

All my projects in Android studio result in below error when I validate AndroidManifest.xml

```
Error:(3, 43) cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'manifest'.
Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'x' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-invalid: Element 'x' is not a valid element in a schema document.
Error:(1, 56) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

The application is not recognizing any of the permissions stated under . I tried `READ_CONTACTS` and S`END_SMS`

I validated AndroidManifest.xml and the xml is fine.

Manifest code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jyo.dedlymenu2" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Love"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_love" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Friendship"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_friendship" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Inspire"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_inspire" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ThankYou"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_thank_you" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AddLyrics"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_lyrics" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LyricDetail"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_lyric_detail" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".PrintDB"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_print_db" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please suggest where am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

clear .idea file in project folder and try to rebuild it... it work

Comment: The issue is with all the projects in my Android studio work space. So I guess the issue is to do with some missing package in the studio installation